# JQM checkbox get checked on tap and then immediately becomes unchecked on android

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using JQM for mobile web application development. I am trying to hide/show a part of the form depending on a checkbox status. This is working fine with iphone but behaving weirdly on android phone like when the user selects the check box it displays that block of form but immediately hides back and gets unchecked automatically. I am new to JQM, please let me know if I missed some thing to mention here.

```
 $('form #addsp').click(function () {
    if ($('form #addsp').is(':checked')) {
        $('#addDetail').show()

    } else {
        $('#addDetail').hide()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$("input[type='checkbox']")[0].attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");

You need to refresh the checkbox to have it checked.

You can read more here: 
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/checkboxes/methods.html

Comment: i do refresh it, but UI is not consistent all the time.